# How do I sum results of two if statements in the same cell?

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, excel-2010, pivot-table

I'm looking to have the results of two If statements calculated and added in the same cell. I'm getting  #VALUE! error.

```
=IF(ISERROR(GETPIVOTDATA("Sum of CHARGES",'Ship City'!$A$3,"ship_city",$B$7,"carrier_type",$A$27,"INV_month_id",D$6,"INV_year_id",$D$5,"Company Name",$B29)),"",GETPIVOTDATA("Sum of CHARGES",'Ship City'!$A$3,"ship_city",$B$7,"carrier_type",$A$27,"INV_month_id",D$6,"INV_year_id",$D$5,"Company Name",$B29))+IF(ISERROR(GETPIVOTDATA("Sum of CHARGES",'Recipient City'!$A$4,"recipient_city",$B$7,"carrier_type",$A$27,"INV_month_id",D$6,"INV_year_id",$D$5,"Company Name",$B29)),"",GETPIVOTDATA("Sum of CHARGES",'Recipient City'!$A$4,"recipient_city",$B$7,"carrier_type",$A$27,"INV_month_id",D$6,"INV_year_id",$D$5,"Company Name",$B29))
```

=IF(ISERROR(GETPIVOTDATA("Sum of CHARGES",'Ship City'!$A$3,"ship_city",$B$7,"carrier_type",$A$27,"INV_month_id",D$6,"INV_year_id",$D$5,"Company Name",$B29)),"",GETPIVOTDATA("Sum of CHARGES",'Ship City'!$A$3,"ship_city",$B$7,"carrier_type",$A$27,"INV_month_id",D$6,"INV_year_id",$D$5,"Company Name",$B29))

+

IF(ISERROR(GETPIVOTDATA("Sum of CHARGES",'Recipient City'!$A$4,"recipient_city",$B$7,"carrier_type",$A$27,"INV_month_id",D$6,"INV_year_id",$D$5,"Company Name",$B29)),"",GETPIVOTDATA("Sum of CHARGES",'Recipient City'!$A$4,"recipient_city",$B$7,"carrier_type",$A$27,"INV_month_id",D$6,"INV_year_id",$D$5,"Company Name",$B29))

Comment: There could be many reasons why you're getting that error - Does each of the 2 formulas produce a value on its own? If so, it probably is a length issue and you should look into the `IFERROR()` function rather than `IF(ISERROR(x),..,x)` way of doing things - That will make your formulas substantially shorter.

Comment: @John Bustos yes they both independently work and produce their own values, I just need to have them computed and added in the same cell. Thank you for your input; ill give it a shot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your both `IF` functions return an empty string `""`. Using `+` operator with strings returns `#VALUE!`. There are different methods to fix it:

- use `0` instead of `""`
- use `SUM` instead of `+` (it ignores strings).

And as @John Bustos mentioned in his comment, you can simplify your formula with

```
IFERROR(value,value_if_error)
```

[IFERROR description](https://support.office.com/en-in/article/IFERROR-function-f59bacdc-78bd-4924-91df-a869d0b08cd5)